# TSQL: Swap two values of the same type in diffrent tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two values of custom type in diffrent tables: DB1.TBL1.Val and DB2.TBL2.Val. Is it possible to swap these to values? These two values are the same type of, this type is datBlob.

Once again: I have database DB1 with table TBL1 that holds many records and have some fields, including Val. Let's say i determined conditions to guarantee that these two returned rows will be correct. The same about the other database DB2. I want swap these 2 values.

In other words I want something like

> UPDATE DB1.TBL1 SET Val=(SELECT Val FROM DB2.Tbl2.Val WHERE MyGUID='WOW') WHERE MyGUID='Wow'

Comment: You have to identify the rows somehow, where the 2 values are. Or you want to "swap" all the values in those 2 columns?

Comment: So? I can identify for example: SELECT DB1.TBL1.Val WHERE OtherUniqueval='{Some GUID}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic swapping of values. You have to write the code to do the job. Below code show how. You have to adapt for data types, table names etc and how you find the rows that needs to be updated.

```
-- Value from DB1
declare @B1 as int

-- Value from DB2
declare @B2 as int

-- Get value from DB1
select @B1 = Val
from DB1.dbo.TBL1.Val
where ID = 1

-- Get value from DB2
select @B2 = Val
from DB2.dbo.TBL2.Val
where ID = 1

-- Update value in DB1
update DB1.dbo.TBL1
set Val = @B2
where ID = 1

-- Update value in DB2
update DB2.dbo.TBL2
set Val = @B1
where ID = 1
```

Comment: Ok, what should i declare if my field is  of type datBlob, not int?

Comment: What is the definition of `datBlob`?

Comment: I cannot guarantee that, but i suspect that is binary BLOB. But DECLARE @val binary dows not work.

Comment: If you have a [user-defined type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) that is called `datBlob` then you can use `datBlob` instead of `int` when you declare the variables. `declare @B1 datBlob`. Make sure that either `DB1` or `DB2` is the current database.